# Processing power for a web application server

Tags: java, sockets, server, virtualization, processor

We are trying to implement a web application that is java based and the requirements from the vendor are "Dual core processor 3.0 GHZ or higher".  The vendor supports virtualization, and we have the server on a Cisco UCS.  We setup the VM to have 4 sockets and use the servers Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.67GHz

To sum it up, the vendor says our processor does not meet specifications and we will see significant slow downs.

Requirements: **Dual core processor 3.0 GHZ or faster** 
Our specs:  **4 CPUs Intel Xeon X5650 @ 2.67 GHZ** 

***Should these specs handle the job?***

I know there are **old Pentiums** that have dual core and 3.0 GHZ speeds, this is an **enterprise grade server processor** and we allocated 4 sockets at 2.67 GHZ each to the server.  Should our server be able to handle the web application?

What is the speed difference between dual core 3 GHz and four sockets using Xeon X5650s at 2.67 GHZ?

Comment: I'm with you - those specs haven't been changed in years and the sales-droid doesn't understand.  Java will appreciate the added processors and modern Xeon processors should do well.  Just curious - does the vendor sell hardware too?

Comment: This is off-topic here.  Decoding / interpreting vendor-suggested CPU suggestions belongs on serverfault if anywhere, I think.  You're almost certainly fine for your app.  There's no general-case answer to the question you asked, though: it depends on how parallel your workload is.  However, there were dual-core P4 CPUs that ran at 3GHz, and even an old [Westmere-EX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westmere_(microarchitecture)) core at 2.67GHz will be way faster for single-threaded stuff.

Comment: Wait a minute, X5650 is 6-core with hyperthreading.  So you mean a 4-socket system, not just single-socket quad-core?  So 4 * 6 = 24 physical cores / 48 logical cores with hyperthreading.  That's absolutely massive overkill above the vendor's dual-core spec.